# Do Changelings within the Great Link have names?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, changeling

Odo, Laas, and perhaps the other Changelings that were sent out to explore the galaxy have names, but do the Changelings within the Great Link also have names?

I realize that the Female Changeling states that "the drop becomes the ocean," or words to that extent, but clearly individual Changelings can separate themselves from the Link and walk around. Do these individuals have names, or are they just "hey yous"?

Comment: They don't seem to have names in general. Those seem to be a construct of the solids. Even the female changeling doesn't take a name when she's running the show in the Alpha Quadrant

Answer (score 4):

Odo and Laas were given names by the [solids](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Mora_Pol) that [they'd encountered](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Varalan).

> **LAAS:** *The Varalans called me Laas. In their language it means changeable. Not very imaginative, is it?*
>
> **ODO:** *At least it's appropriate. My name means unknown sample. The scientist who found me didn't know what I was.*
>
> <sub><sup>[DS9: Chimera](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/564.htm)</sup></sub>

When he finally meets other changelings, he learns that they don't normally communicate using spoken words, preferring a direct mingling of minds in a small version of the Great Link or simply within the Link itself.

**The short answer appears to be that the changelings don't typically use names other than generically identifying themselves as a Founder to their acolytes.**

---

The [Star Trek RPG Module Book 5 (Aliens)](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Roleplaying_Game_(Decipher)) had this to say on the subject;

> *They have no need of their own language, for their merging can
> provide far greater and more immediate communication than words could
> possibly convey. **Changelings adopt names for themselves when operating
> among "solids," but have little use for them on their homeworld.***